# Required field not being shown on password reset page

Tags: 7, users

We have a terms and conditions checkbox boolean which is required to create an account. It's created in the Manage Fields section under People.  We have set that checkbox to Required, and it works. But when a user goes to reset their password the form cannot be submitted because the field is required but it's hidden from the form. In the manage display for the boolean field it's set to display and shows for the user. Any idea why this field is hidden from users on password reset form but not account creation or their profile page?

Answer (score 0):

Fields setup in the Account profiles only appear on the creation/edit forms for users and not the password reset form.

If you have existing users and just recently added the field, you could set the field for your existing user base with [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations); otherwise they won't be able to edit their accounts/reset passwords until the field has been assigned a value on their user account profiles.

This is also true of content types/nodes, when you add a new field with a default value- the default value will only appear for new nodes and not existing ones; likewise any required fields will prevent edits to the existing content until they are populated.

Comment: The issue is when a user creates an account they have to click the Boolean to even create the account, which should be saved to the user account as checked. When they receive an email to set their password, the Boolean field is hidden from the form and the value is unchecked All the other custom fields such as textfields are on the password reset form with the values from account creation, just not the Boolean single on/off checkbox. The only solution right now is too make the checkbox not required which removes the user's required step of accepting the sites terms and conditions.

Comment: Sounds like you're using the "Visitors can register, but email verification is required" setting on new accounts- which forces new users to register email and username, sends an email with the one-time login/password reset link, and then lets users continue the signup process/completing their profile.  If that's the case, you may want to try installing the LoginToboggan module [https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan] which allows users to register their account and fill out the profile without the one-time login password/reset link email; that should bypass the issue you're encountering.

Comment: The problem is that the field is shown in the password reset form, even if it's hidden. The setting to verify the email for every user who registers an account doesn't influence that.